# Comparing arrays that have same elements in different order

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote below code to compare to arrays that have same elements but in diff order.

```
 Integer arr1[] = {1,4,6,7,2};
 Integer arr2[] = {1,2,7,4,6};
```

For example, Above arrays are equal as they same elements 1,2,4,6,7. If you have better code for larger arrays, please share.

**Edit** If unique elements are taken from both the arrays and if they appear to be same, then also array should be equal. How do I write the code without using any collections classes.
Ex: arr1={1,2,3,1,2,3} arr2={3,2,1} Method should return true (=both arrays are same).

```
package com.test;

public class ArrayCompare {

public boolean compareArrays(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2){
    if(arr1==null || arr2==null){
        return false;
    }
    if(arr1.length!=arr2.length){
        return false;
    }

    Integer[] sortedArr1=sortArray(arr1);
    Integer[] sortedArr2=sortArray(arr2);

    for(int i=0;i<sortedArr1.length-1;i++){
        if(sortedArr1[i]!=sortedArr2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
     return true;
}
public void swapElements(Integer[] arr,int pos){
    int temp=arr[pos];
    arr[pos]=arr[pos+1];
    arr[pos+1]=temp;
}
public Integer[] sortArray(Integer[] arr){
    for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                swapElements(arr,i);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer arr1[] = {1,4,6,7,2};
    Integer arr2[] = {1,2,7,4,6};
    ArrayCompare arrComp=new ArrayCompare();
    System.out.println(arrComp.compareArrays(arr1, arr2));
}
```

}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you care about duplicate counts? For example, would you need to distinguish between `{ 1, 1, 2 }` and `{ 1, 2, 2 }`? If not, just use a `HashSet`:

```
public static boolean compareArrays(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2) {
    HashSet<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
    HashSet<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr2));
    return set1.equals(set2);
}
```

If you *do* care about duplicates, then either you could use a `Multiset` from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com).

If you want to stick with the sorting version, why not use the built-in sorting algorithms instead of writing your own?

EDIT: You don't even need to create a copy, if you're happy modifying the existing arrays. For example:

```
public static boolean compareArrays(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2) {
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    return Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
}
```

You can also have an optimization for the case where the arrays aren't the same length:

```
public static boolean compareArrays(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2) {
    // TODO: Null validation...
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    return Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have no duplicates you can turn the arrays into sets:

```
new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1))
    .equals(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr2)))
```

Otherwise:

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1));

Collections.sort(l1);
Collections.sort(l2);

l1.equals(l2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for not mentioning before, But don't want to use collections.

Comment: @abhishek: Why not? If you're going to impose arbitrary restrictions, you should explain your motivations as it may well affect other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the interval of values, you could hold an integer array with the size equal to the maximum element of the sequences. Then traverse each array and increment by 1 the number at the position corresponding to the value in the counter array. At the end, traverse the counter array and determine if all elements that are not 0 are 2. In this case the arrays are equal.

```
int[] counters = new int[MAX];
for(int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
    counters[array1[i]]++;
for(int i = 0; i < length2; i++)
    counters[array2[i]]++;

bool areEqual = true;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    if(counters[i] != 0 && counters[i] != 2) 
    {
        areEqual = false;
        break;
    }
```

This assumes there are no duplicates. If you have duplicates, then in the first two for loops add:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
    if(counters[array1[i]] == 0)
       counters[array1[i]]++;
```

This ensures that any duplicates are not considered after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are **reinventing wheel to sort arrays**.

Use

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

also there are methods to sort primitive types such as int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function it return array:-

```
public static String[] numSame (String[] list1, String[] list2) 
     {  
          int same = 0;  
          for (int i = 0; i <= list1.length-1; i++) 
          {  
             for(int j = 0; j <= list2.length-1; j++) 
             {  
                if (list1[i].equals(list2[j])) 
                {  
                    same++;  
                    break;  
                }  
             }  
          }  

          String [] array=new String[same];
          int p=0;
          for (int i = 0; i <= list1.length-1; i++) 
          {  
             for(int j = 0; j <= list2.length-1; j++) 
             {  
                if (list1[i].equals(list2[j])) 
                {  
                    array[p]=  list1[i]+"";
                    System.out.println("array[p] => "+array[p]);
                    p++;
                    break;  
                }  
             }  
          } 
          return array;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean compairArraysOfDifferentSequence(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2){

    if(arr1 == null || arr2 == null){

        return false;
    }
    if(arr1.length != arr2.length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else{

        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);

        return Arrays.deepEquals(arr1, arr2);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should really start with a `if (arr1 == arr2) return true;` as `Arrays.equals()` does it and it could avoid a lot of work.