# Find same multiplicities in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I need help on my sameElements() method. I need to take two user inputted arrays that are in a random order and see if they have the same multiplicities.

I know if they don't have the same length, then they won't have the same element. But that's all I got. Can my code in my sameSet() method be modified for this? Or do I need to do something entirely different?

```
 ` /**
 * checks whether two arrays have the same elements in some order, with
 * the same multiplicities. For example, 1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11 and 11 1 4 9 16
 * 9 7 4 9 would be considered identical
 *
 */

 public static boolean sameElements(Integer a[], int sizeA, Integer b[], int sizeB) {
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false; 
    }
      // need help on this, length portion is all I have.
 }


 /**
 * check whether two arrays have the same elements in some order, ignoring
 * duplicates. For example, the two arrays 1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11 and 11 11 7 9
 * 16 4 1 would be considered identical.
 */

public static boolean sameSet(Integer[] a, int sizeA, Integer[] b, int sizeB) {

    HashSet<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a)); // Put arrays a & b into hashset */
    HashSet<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(b));

    //Compares the sets to see if they have the same elements 

    if (set1.equals(set2)) {
        System.out.println("The elements of the arrays A and B form the same set.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The elements of the arrays A and B do not1 form the same set.");
    }
    return set1.equals(set2);

}

public static void main() {
    final int LENGTH = 30;
    int sizeA = 0;
    int sizeB = 0;
    Integer a[] = new Integer[LENGTH];
    Integer b[] = new Integer[LENGTH];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please fill up values for array a, Q to quit: "); //Gather user input for array A
        while (input.hasNextInt() && sizeA < a.length) {
            a[sizeA] = input.nextInt();
            sizeA++;
        }
        System.out.println("# of values in array A:" + sizeA + "\n");

        System.out.println("Please fill up values for array b, type in Q to quit: "); //Gather user input for array B
        while (in.hasNextInt() && sizeB < b.length) {
            b[sizeB] = in.nextInt();
            sizeB++;
        }
        System.out.println("# of values in array B:" + sizeB);
        //Take the user input and test it through each method
        equals(a, sizeA, b, sizeB); 
        sameSet(a, sizeA, b, sizeB);
        sameElements(a, sizeA, b, sizeB);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it easily using containsAll method of a Set. I've written the below program. Please check if it helps you.

```
    Set a = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set b = new HashSet<Integer>();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);

    b.add(3);
    b.add(2);
    b.add(1);
    if(a.containsAll(b) && b.containsAll(a))
    {
        System.out.println("Same elements in both");            
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not same elements in both");
    }
```

Comment: Since you know how to convert array into a set, I have left that part in  my code

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to know if the arrays are anagrams of each other. The general solution for that problem is to sort them (`Arrays.sort`) and then check if they are equal.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103629/1980909

Comment: array.sort throws an exception though if all the array values aren't filled though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Maxwell1222 I doubt it does, but even if it did, you could just create your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that doesn't,

Comment: @Maxwell1222 yes. If possible, you should use int[] instead of Integer[].

Answer (score -1):

Sorry.  I did not read the question well.  To do what you want you can order the values in each array by greatest and least then check if they are equal.

<strike>This code here loops through the array and checks each element with the other array's element.</strike>

```
boolean equal = true;//If true after for then it is equal if false then it is not equal.
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; a++){
    if(!a[i].equals(b[i])){
        equal = false;
        break;
    }
}
```