# Why multiply instead of sum

Tags: java, arrays, math

I need to check if two arrays contain the same digits or not. So:

```
[1,1,2] and [1,2,2] = false;
[2,3,1] and [1,2,3] = true;
[1,2,4] and [1,3,2] = false;
[1,1,4] and [1,2,3] = false;
```

Now somehow this works, multiplication:

```
boolean areSimilar(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int s1 = 1, s2 = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        s1 *= a[i];
        s2 *= b[i];
    }
    return s1 == s2;
}
```

But if I replace `*=` with `+=`, so just some it up, `[1,1,4] and [1,2,3]` would return true instead of false (obviously, because it will return 6 is equal to 6).

So my question is, can I make sure that multiplication is fault proof?
Or is it possible that by multiplication it IS possible that 2 arrays contain different numbers but have the same product?

Comment: Of course it's possible!

Comment: Consider the counter example [1,2,4] and [2,2,2]. Product is same but digits are different. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: All this becomes a bit obvious when one considers the case where both arrays contain **0** (zero) as one of their elements... ... ...

Comment: Side fact: It would work, if all your numbers in the arrays are prime.

Comment: Yep, guess it was a silly question now I think about it, but it actually contained an extra check. The idea was actually to check whether or not it is possible to get similar arrays by just swapping at most 1 number of an array (so swap index 1 and 2 of second array and they become equal). If that is not possible they are not equal. So the extra check counted how many times index of array 1 was not equal to index of array 2. If that was more than 2 AND the multiplication failed, it was not possible to get them equal. But even that solution bugs me

Comment: Did you try to combine addition and multiplication `(a*b*c+a+b+c)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the multiplication is not "fault proof" in this sense.

The obvious counterexamples are the ones where both arrays contain **0** (zero) as one of their elements. The product will always be 0, regardless of the other elements. Even if none of the elements is zero, it is simple to find further counterexamples.

Using the multiplication is only "safe" *if and only if* the numbers in the array are the [prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) of the same number. The prime factorization is unique, and the order of the multiplication of the elements does not matter.

*Edit:*

Here, I proposed a solution to the actual problem, namely checking whether two arrays contain the same elements, disregarding the order.

As discussed in the comments, it turns out that although it is *theoretically* (asymptotically) slower, the sorting-based approach proposed in the [answer by dnswlt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823186/3182664) seems to be far more efficient in practice, **if** you don't care about the memory consumption that is implied by cloning the arrays.

The solution that I originally proposed here has the advantage of lower memory consumption, lower *asymptotic* running time, and the fact that it is *conceptually* applicable to other types of elements (particularly, to arrays that contain elements that are not comparable, and thus, cannot be sorted).

The approach is to construct a `Map` for each array. This `Map` maps each element of the array to the *number of times* that it appears in the array:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SameNumbersInArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(areSimilar(
            new int[] { 1, 1, 2 },
            new int[] { 1, 2, 2 }));

        System.out.println(areSimilar(
            new int[] { 2, 3, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));

        System.out.println(areSimilar(
            new int[] { 1, 2, 4 },
            new int[] { 1, 3, 2 }));

        System.out.println(areSimilar(
            new int[] { 1, 1, 4 },
            new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));

        System.out.println(areSimilar(
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 4 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 4 }));

        System.out.println(areSimilar(
            new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 4 },
            new int[] { 1, 1, 4, 1 }));

    }

    private static boolean areSimilar(int[] a, int[] b) {

        Map<Integer, Long> frequenciesA = IntStream.of(a).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        Map<Integer, Long> frequenciesB = IntStream.of(b).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        return frequenciesA.equals(frequenciesB);
    }

}
```

The output for the test cases is

```
false
true
false
false
false
true
```

However, for `int[]` arrays, the sorting-based approach is more efficient in practice (likely due to the costly boxing conversions that are done for the counting-based approach).

Comment: Thank for your explanation! The 0 does make much sense XD So guess I have to find another solution

Comment: Thanks for your complete solution! Looks good! One question though, don't you think sorting the two arrays and check if they are equal with (`Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);`) actually is easier? Or does that solution has some disadvantages?

Comment: Sorting and comparing is an option, with two **theoretical** drawbacks: 1. Sorting an array is O(nlogn), whereas my proposed solution is O(n). But in practice (based on a quick test), sorting and comparing (as proposed in the [answer by dnswlt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823186/3182664) , +1! ) seems to be always be more efficient. 2. If you don't want to modifiy the given arrays, you have to create copies of the arrays, which may consume a lot of memory for large arrays.

Comment: An (also **theoretical**) advantage of the counting-based approach: If you compute the frequencies for one array, and end up e.g. with finding that `3` appears 10 times, then you **could** do an optimization: If, while processing the second array, you find that `3` appears **11** times, you can already return `false`. But then, the implementation would not be as simple, and whether this brings an advantage in practice heavily depends on the contents of the arrays that are compared.

Comment: Also IMO sorting and comparing produces cleaner code because it is very easy to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @MarkusK Yes, I already edited the answer accordingly. The stream/map/counting based approach might indeed look a bit obscure at the first glance. And its **theorerical** benefits (less memory, asymptotically faster, applicable to non-sortable types) probably don't outweigh the clarity that can be achived with the sort-based solution, when all this is really just about `int[]` arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it is possible that the product is the same with differenz digits in it. Example: [9 1 2]   [18 1 1]

I whould suggest a different solution.

When you first sort the arrays you can check wether each digit is the same.

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out, obviously neither adding nor multiplying suffices. A typical sort-based solutions looks as follows:

```
boolean areSimilar(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }
    int[] aSorted = a.clone();
    Arrays.sort(aSorted);
    int[] bSorted = b.clone();
    Arrays.sort(bSorted);
    return Arrays.equals(aSorted, bSorted);
}
```

Note that I use `clone()` to ensure your original arrays remain unmodified. If that does not matter, you can sort `a` and `b` directly.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103629/7653073) to a similar question. You don't need to compare the elements yourself, use `Arrays.equals(a1, a2)`.

Comment: Cheers for the hint, adapted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, multiplication is not fault proof.

Consider the arrays {1,1,6} and {1,2,3}. They have the same product (6), but different digits.

Comment: My stab: It is "fault proof" **if and only if** the numbers in the array are the prime factorization of a (the same) number.

Comment: But by the same token, adding doesn't work either, e.g. `{1,1,8}` and `{1,2,7}`.

Comment: Guess it was a silly question. The actual idea was I needed to check whether it is possible to generate similar arrays by just swapping at most one number. So there was an extra check which checked how many times an index of an and the other array, didn't contain the same values. If it was less or equal to 2 AND the multiplication failed, it wasn't possible to get them equal by just swapping 1 number

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with either addition *or* multiplication.

You are trying to map N 32 bit numbers to a single 32 bit number. That is data compression. You can't fit 32*N bits of information into 32 bits, just like you can't put N litres of waters into a litre bottle (unless N is 1, of course).

Sometimes, you can exploit some properties of the data so that you require fewer than `32*N` bits of information: for example, if you know your numbers are between 0 and 15, you only require 4 bits per number. But in the general case, you can't.

Quite simply, there are always going to be "collisions", where two different arrays map to the same value.

What you *can* do is say that the numbers are definitely *not* the same. You can do this with the multiplication or addition method: if the products or sums of two arrays are different, they definitely aren't the same; if they are, you have to do a further level of checking to see if the numbers are they same.

This is the basis of the `hashCode` method: when implemented correctly, `hashCode` allows you to determine whether two instances *aren't* equal; if you want to know if they *are* equal, you have to use the `equals` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, Andy. Makes much sense. Guess Malte Hartwig's answer was helpful as well (first sort arrays and then check if they are equal, if not one array contains a different set of numbers).

Comment: @ErikvandeVen that's a "further level of checking": do the simple addition or multiplication check first (maybe even check their lengths before that!), that allows you to avoid always having to do the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication is not fault proof.
This is just a quick check. somewhat like a shorthand to find if a comparisopn is even worth doing. a checksum (here check multiply) kind of check.

> [0, x, y, z, ...] == [..a,b, 0, c ...] always

Answer (score 0):

Why not combining sum and product? (equivalent java-code below)

## Scala:

```
val r = scala.util.Random 
// 10 digits produce to few collisions to control by hand:
// def arr = Vector (r.nextInt (10), r.nextInt (10), r.nextInt (10)) 
def arr = Vector (r.nextInt (3), r.nextInt (3), r.nextInt (3)) 
// first idea: a*b*c + a+b+c, but  3,0,0 and 2,1,0 produce 
// product 0 and sum 3  
// def checksum (v: Vector[Int]) : Int = v.product +  v.sum
// so we just add 1 to every digit 
def checksum (v: Vector[Int]) : Int = (v(0)+1)*(v(1)+1)*(v(2)+1) +  v(0)+v(1)+v(2) 
def cmp (a:Vector[Int], b:Vector[Int]) : Boolean = { checksum(a) == checksum(b)} 
(1 to 30).foreach (i => {val a=arr; val b=arr; val m = cmp (a, b); println (s"match: $a $b $m") })
```

## Testdata:

```
match: Vector(0, 1, 2) Vector(0, 1, 0) false
match: Vector(1, 1, 0) Vector(2, 1, 1) false
match: Vector(2, 1, 0) Vector(2, 0, 2) false
match: Vector(0, 0, 2) Vector(0, 1, 1) false
match: Vector(2, 1, 1) Vector(2, 1, 1) true
match: Vector(0, 1, 1) Vector(1, 0, 2) false
match: Vector(2, 0, 2) Vector(2, 0, 0) false
match: Vector(0, 2, 2) Vector(2, 1, 0) false
match: Vector(2, 2, 2) Vector(0, 1, 2) false
match: Vector(2, 2, 0) Vector(1, 1, 0) false
match: Vector(0, 2, 2) Vector(0, 0, 2) false
match: Vector(0, 2, 1) Vector(2, 1, 1) false
match: Vector(0, 2, 1) Vector(1, 0, 0) false
match: Vector(2, 2, 2) Vector(2, 1, 1) false
match: Vector(0, 1, 1) Vector(1, 0, 2) false
match: Vector(1, 0, 0) Vector(1, 0, 2) false
match: Vector(2, 1, 1) Vector(0, 1, 2) false
match: Vector(2, 0, 0) Vector(2, 1, 0) false
match: Vector(1, 2, 1) Vector(2, 1, 2) false
match: Vector(2, 2, 1) Vector(2, 1, 2) true
match: Vector(0, 0, 0) Vector(0, 2, 2) false
match: Vector(2, 0, 1) Vector(0, 1, 1) false
match: Vector(2, 0, 1) Vector(1, 2, 1) false
match: Vector(0, 1, 1) Vector(1, 1, 0) true
match: Vector(0, 2, 0) Vector(1, 0, 0) false
match: Vector(1, 2, 1) Vector(0, 1, 0) false
match: Vector(2, 0, 2) Vector(0, 1, 0) false
match: Vector(0, 1, 0) Vector(1, 2, 2) false
match: Vector(1, 1, 0) Vector(0, 0, 0) false
match: Vector(0, 1, 1) Vector(0, 2, 1) false
```

Still much to control case by case, I'will write a check function, which orders the Vectors before comparing. I guess, while the code is scala, it's easy to understand and translate into java equivalence?

```
def cmp2 (a:Vector[Int], b:Vector[Int]) : Boolean = { a.sorted == b.sorted} 
(1 to 3000).foreach (i => {val a=arr; val b=arr; if (cmp (a, b) != cmp2 (a, b)) println (s"match: $a $b ${cmp(a,b)} ${cmp2(a,b)}") })
// silence
```

Of course, you can do a mathematical proof too:

```
(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)+a+b+c ?= (d+a+1)*(e+b+1)*(c+1)+(d+a)+b+c | d!=0
// or
(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)+a+b+c ?= (d+a+1)*(e+b+1)*(c+1)+(d+a)+b+c | d!=0, e!=0
```

That's left as an exercise for the reader, as usual :)

## Java:

```
Random r = new java.util.Random();

int [] arr (int max) {
  int[] v = new int[3];
  v[0] = r.nextInt (max);
  v[1] = r.nextInt (max);
  v[2] = r.nextInt (max);
  return v;
}

int checksum (int[] v) { return (v[0] +1) * (v[1] +1) * (v[2] +1) + v[0] + v[1] + v[2]; }

boolean cmp (int[] a, int[] b) { return checksum(a) == checksum(b); } 

for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
  int [] a = arr (3); 
  int [] b = arr (3); 
  boolean m = cmp (a, b); 
  System.out.printf ("match: %6s %6s %b\n",  Arrays.toString (a), Arrays.toString (b), m);
}
```